# How to reboot device by using alarm manager in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reboot

I need to store the last rebooted time of the device and if reboot does not happened in a day then device should restart 
1) I got the rebooted time by taking the time when device was started and storing it.
2) I add 24 hours to the rebooted time 
3) My device is rooted so I just execute shell command "su -c reboot" to restart the device

My question is how can I trigger an alarm and execute shell command to restart my device?
I was thinking of alarm manager but pending intent takes only activities, services and broadcast receivers but not a piece of code. 
Can some one suggest any alternative way?

Comment: Put your code in a service?

Comment: Hi, I am searching the solution for the same issue, I need to restart the android tablet periodically, did you find out the solution..? Please help me out..